# AS3 - How to store and use an array in an XML file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm making a simple level editor in Flash (using AS3) and I use a 2D array of values to place squares on the screen.

Lets say I have this array (really simple example):

```
var level1:Array = new Array[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]];
```

(Where 0 represents nothing and 1 represents a square)

How would I store that array in an XML file so that the game can then read that information from the XML file?

I'm a complete noob with XML (never used it).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Zoron19

Answer (score 1):

For something so simple it would be a waste to use XML.

You can easily store this as plain text using `join()` and then use `split()` to convert it back into an array. Here's an example of converting a 2D array into a string and then back into an array. First we have the function that will convert your array into the string for storage:

```
function levelToString(input:Array):String
{
    var output:Array = [];
    for each(var i:Array in input)
    {
        output.push(i.join(","));
    }

    return output.join("#");
}
```

And an example using your level data:

```
var level:Array = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]];
trace(levelToString(level)); // 0,0,0,0,0#1,1,1,1,1
```

Now we can use this function to convert that back to the 2D array:

```
function levelToArray(input:String):Array
{
    var base:Array = input.split("#");
    var output:Array = [];

    for each(var i:String in base)
    {
        output.push(i.split(","));
    }

    return output;
}
```

And an example using the string we got above:

```
var array:Array = levelToArray("0,0,0,0,0#1,1,1,1,1");
trace(array[0]); // 0,0,0,0
trace(array[1]); // 1,1,1,1
```

Using this method, your data is much smaller.

Now onto storing and loading that data. If you want to use XML, you can store the level data against `<level>` nodes quite easily. Say you have this in an XML file called `levels.xml`:

```
<levels>
    <level name="first">0,0,0,0,0#1,1,1,1,1</level>
    <level name="second">0,1,0,0,0#1,1,1,0,0</level>
</levels>
```

To load that data into the game, you'll need to use `URLLoader`:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("levels.xml");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataLoaded);

function dataLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var xml:XML = e.target.data as XML;

    // Described below.
    loadLevel(xml, "first");
}
```

And then the `loadLevel` function can take the data and load the level from it:

```
function loadLevel(sourceXML:XML, levelName:String):void
{
    var levelData:Array = levelToArray(sourceXML.level.(@name == levelName));
    trace(levelData);

    // Work with the loaded data array.
    //
}
```

Comment: I understand how all this works, but, how would I place that String in an external file and also load it back into Flash?

Comment: @Zoron19 I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: How does the level information even get into an XML file? I need to know how to store the array in an XML file before I can load it.

Comment: @Zoron19 You typically put it there manually... There's no reason to store small amounts of array data into an external XML file only to have to load it back in again is there? An XML file is manually set up by you so that the data isn't stored directly into the game itself. This is only necessary when there is a lot of level data and you don't want to load it all upfront. XML might also be generated by server-side code (like PHP) by pulling levels out of a database and building the XML from that, which is more advanced.

Comment: Ok, I haven't been that clear about what I want to do. I am going to have a separate Flash program as the level editor. So I want to be able to share the array data between the game and the editor. Sorry that I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: @Zoron19 Unless you're using AIR, you won't be able to save data to a file. If you want to use AIR and do that it's cool but I don't have much experience and won't be able to help you. Another thing you could do though is just have a window which displays the current level data as a string using my function above and paste that into your XML manually. You could also set up a database to store all the data like I mentioned before but that involves learning a couple other languages and software.

Comment: Ok, well I'll figure something out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example

The xml file named levels.xml, each row have a id indicates the row number, and the value is a string(as you mentioned)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<levels>
     <row id="1">0,0,0,0,0</row>
     <row id="2">1,1,1,1,1</row>
</levels>
```

Load the xml and get value

```
 var xmlPath:String = "levels.xml";
 var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
 loader.load(new URLRequest(xmlPath));


 protected function onLoadComplete(event:Event):void {
     var xml:XML = XML(event.target.data);

     var nodes:String = String(xml.row.(@id == 1));//nodes value is 0,0,0,0,0
}
```

Hero is a link about some simple examples about xml in as3 [as3 xml example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html)

Comment: Why does no one include how to store the data in an XML file? You've told me how to load the XML into Flash, but how does the Array even get into the XML?

Comment: You should make a tool to generate the xml,  I think it's not hard. The tool could be a air file. Check out this doc, hope it help http://www.adobe.com/cn/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/xml_prefs.html